# SecItemCopyMatching returns -25300

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following codesnippet in my app.

```
    CFTypeRef result = nil;
    OSStatus userPresenceStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
```

SecItemCopyMatching returns -25300. It happens on some iPhone 6 devices but not on every device. What does this code mean ? What can be the cause ?

Thanks for your advice
Frank

Answer (score 10):

[Error `25300` is `errSecItemNotFound`, which means that there is no such item in your key chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538150/iphone4-secitemcopymatching-returns-25300-after-reboot).

And you can find [a list of potential result codes for Keychain Services here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1542001-security_framework_result_codes).

I'm guessing the keychain item you are trying to match against doesn't exist on that particular device.

Comment: The link above is invalid, you can try this case: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1542001-security_framework_result_codes and for errSecItemNotFound - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/errsecitemnotfound

Answer (score 0):

Faced one more condition which can return an error -25300. Make sure that the data passed to **kSecMatchIssuers** or **kSecMatchSearchList** is of the same type. Loop through all filters and for each call **SecItemCopyMatching**

This is how you find the problematic element!